# Get the running AutoCAD application using comtypes in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, com, autocad, comtypes

I'm trying to fetch an instance to point to the already running AutoCAD 2016 application, or to create a new instance if it's not running.

Here's a simple code sample for that:

```
#Import needed modules
import os
import comtypes.client
from comtypes import COMError
from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetModule, GetActiveObject

try:
        acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.20")
        print "AutoCAD is Active"
        print "########"
except(OSError, COMError): #If AutoCAD isn't running, run it
        acad = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application.20",dynamic=True)
        print "AutoCAD is successfuly Opened"
        print "########"
```

When AutoCAD isn't running, the function `CreateObject` works successfully & only if `dynamic` is set to `true` .. but `GetActiveObject` throws the Traceback error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 112, in GetBestInterface
    interface = getattr(mod, itf_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IAcadApplication'
```

I've seen [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/comtypes/mailman/comtypes-users/thread/loom.20080404T200235-907%40post.gmane.org/) but with no clue.

Also, I've returned to the documentation of comtypes, it says

> The GetActiveObject function succeeds when the COM object is already running, and has registered itself in the COM running object table. Not all COM objects do this.

but this also doesn't give me any clue.

*P.S `GetActiveObject` works well with me with other applications such as ETABS 2016 & SAP2000 v18*

**Any help & insightful responses will be totally appreciated, thanks in advance**

Comment: > GetActiveObject throws <
it's CreateObject in the stack trace?

Comment: @Maxence Yes, I just removed the first part that points to the line
`acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.20")`, in other words, the problem **most likely** resides in the coding of comtypes itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird but it does work (at least with me)

I went to the `gen` folder, its full path is `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen`, then looked for the file AutoCAD.py, opened it in IDLE, knew its equivalent generated symbol (ID) such as `_4E3F492A_FB57_4439_9BF0_1567ED84A3A9_0_1_0`, then deleting these 4 files:

1. AutoCAD.py
2. AutoCAD.pyc
3. _4E3F492A_FB57_4439_9BF0_1567ED84A3A9_0_1_0.py
4. _4E3F492A_FB57_4439_9BF0_1567ED84A3A9_0_1_0.pyc

You can notice that the last 2 files are named by the same equivalent generated symbol which is mentioned in the file AutoCAD.py .